# Substitute parenthesis for their regular expression

Tags: python, regex, parentheses

I'm trying to copy a file,

```
>>> originalFile = '/Users/alvinspivey/Documents/workspace/Image_PCA/spectra_text/HIS/jean paul test 1 - Copy (2)/bean-1-aa.txt'
>>> copyFile = os.system('cp '+originalFile+' '+NewTmpFile)
```

But must first replace the spaces and parenthesis before the open function will work:

/Users/alvinspivey/Documents/workspace/Image_PCA/spectra_text/HIS/jean\ paul\ test\ 1\ -\ Copy\ \(2\)/bean-1-aa.txt

spaces      ' '  --> '\ '
parenthesis '('  --> '\('  etc.

Replacing the spaces work:

```
>>> originalFile = re.sub(r'\s',r'\ ', os.path.join(root,file))
```

but parenthesis return an error:

```
>>> originalFile = re.sub(r'(',r'\(', originalFile)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 151, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 244, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: unbalanced parenthesis

Am I replacing parenthesis correctly?

Also, when using re.escape() for this, the file is not returned correctly.  So it is not an alternative.

Comment: You can use [shutil.copy](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html) (copy2, or copyfile) instead of the system cp command, thus avoiding the need to escape the path in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(` has special meaning in regular expressions (grouping), you have to escape it:

```
originalFile = re.sub(r'\(',r'\(', originalFile)
```

or, since you don't use regex features for the replacement:

```
originalFile = re.sub(r'\(','\(', originalFile)
```

Answer (score 2):

The regular expression `r'('` is translated as start a capturing group. Which is why Python is complaining.

If all you are doing is replacing spaces and parenthesis then maybe just [string.replace](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.replace) will do ?

Comment: +1 for string.replace(). "Do the simplest thing that could possibly work".

Comment: Thanks, string.replace works well and I'll switch my programming style to using it now.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, if you avoid calling a shell (os.system) to do the copy, you don't need to worry about escaping spaces and other special characters,

```
import shutil

originalFile = '/Users/alvinspivey/Documents/workspace/Image_PCA/spectra_text/HIS/jean paul test 1 - Copy (2)/bean-1-aa.txt'
newTmpFile = '/whatever.txt'
shutil.copy(originalFile, newTmpFile)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use shutil.copy to copy files, rather than calling the system.
2. Use subprocess rather than os.system - it avoids calling into the shell, so doesn't need the quoting.

Comment: Thanks @mwalsh and Douglas, shutil.copy is nice.  But, only fixes the problem at one line.  Thanks though.

Comment: That's where you need subprocess.